# Printing row with highest value

Tags: bash, awk, text-processing

Given following output derived from `df -P | awk '!/udev|boot|tmpfs|none/ && NR>1 {printf ("%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\n", $1, $2, $6)}' | grep -wv /`.

```
/dev/sda2       576075280       /hdd
/dev/sda1       1344681704      /home
/dev/vda2       2468687261      /media/user/backup
/dev/vda1       823581356       /media/user/movie
/dev/sdb2       676075280       /media/user/db2
/dev/sdb1       1691481049      /media/user/db1
```

I want to select row with largest storage from each partition, the desired output would be.

```
/dev/sda1       1344681704      /home
/dev/vda2       2468687261      /media/pi/backup
/dev/sdb1       1691481049      /media/pi/db1
```

Comment: Ah, I meant the partition devices (e.g. `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda1`), but I guess it shouldn't matter if I only looking for highest value from each partition.

Comment: The problem is that partitions can have more complex names than in your example (e.g., `/dev/disk1s5s1` or `/dev/mapper/hdd-home`). Not mentioning loop devices (`/dev/loop2`). So, please edit your question and explain how you extract the device name from the partition names (remove the trailing number? other?).

Comment: Whatever you're doing with `grep -wv /` you don't need as awk can do it in the same command you're already using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux you can just use `lsblk` instead of `df` for finding the biggest partition of each disk:

```sh
lsblk -nPpbo KNAME,SIZE,PKNAME,MOUNTPOINT |

awk -F'="|" ?' -v OFS='\t' '
    {
        kname = $2       # device name, for ex. /dev/sda1
        size = $4        # size of the device, in Bytes
        pkname = $6      # parent device name, for ex. /dev/sda 
        mountpoint = $8  # where the device is mounted, absolute path
    }

    pkname !~ "^/" { next }
    mountpoint !~ "^/" { next }
    mountpoint == "/" { next } # not sure why you want to exclude /

    size > sizes[pkname] {
        knames[pkname] = kname
        sizes[pkname] = size
        mountpoints[pkname] = mountpoint
    }

    END {
        for (pkname in knames)
            print knames[pkname], sizes[pkname], mountpoints[pkname]
    }
'
```

<sup>**remark:** the size will be displayed in Bytes instead of 512 or 1024 blocks, and possibly problematic characters in the fields (mostly in the mount point) will be escaped with a two digits hexadecimal notation `\xHH`. IMHO both of those are good points because you'll be able to read and unescape the resulting TSV accurately with bash.</sup>

---

Here are the relevant options taken from `lsblk` documentation:

> **-b, --bytes**
>       
> Print the SIZE column in bytes rather than in a human-readable format.
> **-n, --noheadings**
>       
> Do not print a header line.
> **-P, --pairs**
>       
> Produce output in the form of `key="value"` pairs.
>       
> All potentially unsafe characters are hex-escaped (`\x<code>`).
> **-p, --paths**
>       
> Print full device paths.
> **-o, --output list**
>       
> Specify which output columns to print. [...]
>
>       
> **KNAME**  internal kernel device name
>       
> **MOUNTPOINT**  where the device is mounted
>       
> **SIZE**  size of the device
>       
> **PKNAME**  internal parent kernel device name

Comment: I'm excluding the root partition `/`.

Comment: I know, I'm also excluding it, along with all mountpoints that don't start with `/` (see the `{next}` lines in the awk program). but before that, have a look at the output of `lsblk -pbo KNAME,SIZE,PKNAME,MOUNTPOINT`, you'll understand why I'm advising to use `lsblk` instead of `df`

Comment: Yes, actually when I first wrote this question-- I did not consider the possibility of various devices naming (`/dev/sda`, `/dev/mapper` etc.) so I just thought of using `df` because of its portability.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

```sh
cat input.txt |
  awk '{print substr($1, 1, match($1, "[[:digit:]]") - 1), $0}' |
  sort -k1,1 -k3,3nr |
  awk 'id!=$1{ print; id = $1}' | cut -d ' ' -f2-
```

### Input

```
λ cat input.txt 
/dev/sda2       576075280       /hdd
/dev/sda1       1344681704      /home
/dev/vda2       2468687261      /media/user/backup
/dev/vda1       823581356       /media/user/movie
/dev/sdb2       676075280       /media/user/db2
/dev/sdb1       1691481049      /media/user/db1
```

### Output

```
/dev/sda1       1344681704      /home
/dev/sdb1       1691481049      /media/user/db1
/dev/vda2       2468687261      /media/user/backup
```

## Explanation

1. Here we use a technique called [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).
2. Your question is ambiguous because we don't know how you would consider 2 partitions are the same. Here I use the command `awk '{print substr($1, 1, match($1, "[[:digit:]]") - 1), $0}'` but you can change it to achieve your needs.

   ```sh
   λ cat input.txt | awk '{print substr($1, 1, match($1, "[[:digit:]]") - 1), $0}'                                                                     
   /dev/sda /dev/sda2       576075280       /hdd
   /dev/sda /dev/sda1       1344681704      /home
   /dev/vda /dev/vda2       2468687261      /media/user/backup
   /dev/vda /dev/vda1       823581356       /media/user/movie
   /dev/sdb /dev/sdb2       676075280       /media/user/db2
   /dev/sdb /dev/sdb1       1691481049      /media/user/db1
   ```
3. After adding an extra field as partition identifier, we can easily solve your problem by using combination of `sort`, `awk` and `cut`.

Comment: A "Schwartzian Transform" is the implementation of the DSU (Decorate/Sort/Undecorate) idiom in perl. You're not using perl so you're not using a Schwraztian Transform you're simply using DSU.

Comment: I am not using Lisp so it's not DSU neither. Any other suggestioned terms for the technique?

Comment: DSU doesn't only apply to Lisp, it's the general term across all languages, e.g. see https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#The_Old_Way_Using_Decorate-Sort-Undecorate for Python. Calling it a Schwartzian Transform would be like if you showed an implementation of Insertion Sort in awk and we started calling it a Jianian Transform.

Comment: I thought Schwartzian Transform is also a general term too according to the definition on wiki.

Comment: If it is really for perl specifically. I would appreciate if you show me a reference.

Comment: As the page you referenced states `The term "Schwartzian transform" indicates a specific idiom, and not the algorithm in general`. The history itself describes how that term originated as a reference to a usenet article, not to the algorithm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244053/discussion-between-weihang-jian-and-ed-morton).